# Can't get account_id from Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I'm currently trying to use Google My Business API to get reviews for each location of my company. The problem is that i want to use the reviews methods but I can't use them without my account_id. To have it i know i can do the following request:

https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts

The problem is that when I try to execute it, I have a 429 error saying that the quota of requests for the mybusinessaccountmanagement is exceeded. When I go to the My Business Account Manager page on my Google Cloud Platform Console, i can see that the Quota for this API is setted at 0 and I can't modify it because they ask for my account to have a facturation account.

Do you have any idea of how can I get my account_id to make my request with the Google My Business API?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Google My Business API is restricted by default because of its ability to access sensitive information and so requires approval before you are allowed to use it.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access

The prerequisites page calls this out and provides a link to the form to submit your application to gain access. Until you are approved through that process, your API quota will stay at 0.